# Difference between bootstrap carousels and how to set up?

Tags: views, blocks

I have tried to add the [bootstrap_carousel](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_carousel) to the [Bootstrap Business](https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap_business) template. I have researched every possible forumpost about this slider, but can't get it to work.

Now, the slider works perfectly just as content, but I want to create a view in order to implement it on every page as a banner. Therefore, I followed [this guide](https://www.drupal.org/node/2295021).

My view does not work. I get to see this:

[image]

My settings for that view are:

[image]

Anyone with an idea about what's going wrong? Again, my content type itself is displaying fine, as you can see in the following screenshot. It is the view that is not working.

[image]

## UPDATE

I inserted a custom block with PHP code, but now I have a new problem. Sometimes, two images become active:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution (credit also goes to J. Reynolds., however I went for a different solution so I'm adding it here)

1. set jquery to 1.7
2. disable js CDN load in theme settings
3. add "scripts[] = js/bootstrap.min.js" in theme info file
4. copy paste bootstrap.min.js version 3.0.2 into js folder of your theme
5. insert custom block, copy paste custom block number 14 (slideshow) from [here](https://github.com/morethanthemes/bootstrap-business/blob/master/db_instances/db_instance.sql)
6. include this custom block as banner on homepage
7. See the carousel in action

Answer (score 0):

Do not use Views Bootstrap module. Rather just display the node (of type Carousel) full content.

Construct your view as follows:

**Format:** Unformatted list, show Content, Full Content

**Filter Criteria:** Content:type (= Carousel)

**Pager:** show 1 item only.

Set jQuery update to 1.9 and load [jquery-migrate](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.js)

Your theme pulls Boostrap from CDN. Bootstrap Carousel requires another Bootstrap library in libraries folder. Is this optimal? I don't think so.

Comment: Thanks, your answer set me on the right track. However, I just decided to go with https://www.drupal.org/node/2149669 . Basically I inserted the custom block directly into the db. This is not as customizable as I wanted but it works.